# python pandas .apply() function index error

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
                              P     N  ID  Year  Month
TS                                                    
2016-06-26 19:30:00  263.600006   5.4   5  2016      6
2016-06-26 20:00:00  404.700012   5.6   5  2016      6
2016-06-26 21:10:00  438.600006   6.0   5  2016      6
2016-06-26 21:20:00  218.600006   5.6   5  2016      6
2016-07-02 16:10:00  285.300049  15.1   5  2016      7
```

I'm trying to add a new column based on the values of columns `Year` and `Month` something like the following

```
def exp_records(row):
    return calendar.monthrange(row['Year'], row['Month'])[1]
df['exp_counts'] = df.apply(exp_records, axis=1)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: ('integer argument expected, got float', 'occurred at index 2016-06-26 19:30:00')

If I however `reset_index()` to integer then the above `.apply()` works fine. Is this the expected behavior?

I'm using using pandas 0.19.1 with Python 3.4

---

Code to recreate the DataFrame:

```
s = '''
TS,P,N,ID,Year,Month
2016-06-26 19:30:00,263.600006,5.4,5,2016,6
2016-06-26 20:00:00,404.700012,5.6,5,2016,6
2016-06-26 21:10:00,438.600006,6.0,5,2016,6
2016-06-26 21:20:00,218.600006,5.6,5,2016,6
2016-07-02 16:10:00,285.300049,15.1,5,2016,7
'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Interestingly, when the index is of datetime, `loc`, `iloc` etc returns floats even when the column type is integer. That's probably a bug. You can change `row['Year']` to `int(row['Year'])` as a workaround (and month too, of course). Or you can easily do `df.index.days_in_month`.

Comment: @ayhan: Also, when I tested the given data set with all `int` dtypes, then it returned the values appropriately. But when one of them was changed to `float`, then it coerced all columns to float type(supplying `reduce=False` also didn't help). That's why it was complaining to supply `int` as it's inputs. Moreover, this isn't specific to `datetime`, even integer indices show a similar behavior.

Comment: @NickilMaveli Yes I was also experimenting with float indices and I see the same issue with DataFrames having columns with different dtypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution

Use `df[['Year', 'Month']]` for apply:

```
df['exp_counts'] = df[['Year', 'Month']].apply(exp_records, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                              P     N  ID  Year  Month  exp_counts
TS                                                                
2016-06-26 19:30:00  263.600006   5.4   5  2016      6          30
2016-06-26 20:00:00  404.700012   5.6   5  2016      6          30
2016-06-26 21:10:00  438.600006   6.0   5  2016      6          30
2016-06-26 21:20:00  218.600006   5.6   5  2016      6          30
2016-07-02 16:10:00  285.300049  15.1   5  2016      7          31
```

#### Reason

While your `Year` and `Month` columns are integer:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 5 entries, 2016-06-26 19:30:00 to 2016-07-02 16:10:00
Data columns (total 5 columns):
P        5 non-null float64
N        5 non-null float64
ID       5 non-null int64
Year     5 non-null int64
Month    5 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(3)
memory usage: 240.0 bytes
```

You access them by row, which makes them floats:

```
df.T.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, P to Month
Data columns (total 5 columns):
2016-06-26 19:30:00    5 non-null float64
2016-06-26 20:00:00    5 non-null float64
2016-06-26 21:10:00    5 non-null float64
2016-06-26 21:20:00    5 non-null float64
2016-07-02 16:10:00    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes
```

Since `df.apply(exp_records, axis=1)` goes by row, you essentially convert to rows.

This is what you get in `exp_records` for `row`:

```
P         263.600006
N           5.400000
ID          5.000000
Year     2016.000000
Month       6.000000
Name: 2016-06-26T19:30:00.000000000, dtype: float64
```

Creating a dataframe with the columns `Year` and `Month` only, does cause a converting to float because both columns a integers:

```
df[['Year', 'Month']].T.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, Year to Month
Data columns (total 5 columns):
2016-06-26 19:30:00    2 non-null int64
2016-06-26 20:00:00    2 non-null int64
2016-06-26 21:10:00    2 non-null int64
2016-06-26 21:20:00    2 non-null int64
2016-07-02 16:10:00    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(5)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this has solved my problem. Solution proposed @ayhan is significantly faster but is always good to investigate further.