# Pandas apply returns indexing error even though indices look to be correct

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, apply

I'm getting an index error, and I don't know how to fix it: `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).` I don't understand why it is throwing this error, because the indices shown in the `display()` calls are consistent.

I tried the double brackets in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832754/python-pandas-apply-function-index-error), but it did not work.

The repeatable example below is based on a heavily simplified version of the real code. The error is thrown in the last line.

Using Python 3.7.

```
import pandas as pd

def myfcn(row, data, delta=200):
    # do things here that add a new column
    # and only populate column
    # for the true indices in "pts"
    print(row)

col1 = ['A','A','A','A','B','B']
col2 = [-1,2.1,7,0,3,4]
col3 = ['yes','yes','no','yes','yes','no']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1, col2, col3)), columns =['grp', 'value', 'descrip'])

mask = (
        df['grp'].isin(['A', 'B']) &
        (df['value'] > 0)
)

subset = df[mask]
pts = subset['descrip'] == 'yes'
display(df)
display(subset)
display(pts)

df[pts].apply(myfcn, axis=1, args=(subset, ))
# also tried df[[pts]].apply(myfcn, axis=1, args=(subset, ))
```

[image]

Expected Output: 
[image]

Comment: When using Boolean indexing the indexer must have the same size as the index. You are mixing two techniques here: masking and Boolean indexing. Choose one strategy and stick to it, it should solve the problem.

Comment: what is the purpose of myfnc?  there is no code. how was the new column determined

Comment: @GoldenLion it's not important for the purposes of producing a minimum reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the code is not repeatable.  200 assigned to row 1 and 4 are random without the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to index the `df` with `pts`, which is a Pandas Series containing True/False values. When you pass something to `df` with square brackets the default behavior is to try to select the columns of the DataFrame using the indices in the object passed, which just doesn't make any sense in this case.

If you want to use the condition created in the `pts` object to select only rows in `df` where `pts` is True, you can do:

`df.loc[pts[pts].index]`

Though that is a little clumsy, and you could just index using the full set of conditions in your example (if that's what you need in your real use case):

```
df.loc[
    (df['grp'].isin(['A', 'B'])) &
    (df['value'] > 0) & 
    (df['descrip'] == 'yes')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with assign `loc`

```
df.loc[pts.index[pts],'new_col'] = 200
df
Out[86]: 
  grp  value descrip  new_col
0   A   -1.0     yes      NaN
1   A    2.1     yes    200.0
2   A    7.0      no      NaN
3   A    0.0     yes      NaN
4   B    3.0     yes    200.0
5   B    4.0      no      NaN
```